# Why would I have a non-null HttpContext.Current when I am accessing the context from an NT service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, authentication, httpcontext

The problem that I am facing is that `HttpContext.Current` is **NOT** null when we expect it to be.

My application has a shared class used for authenticating users. A user may either be authenticated using Windows authentication or Forms authentication. This code checks to see if `HttpContext.Current` is null. If it isn't, we attempt to authenticate using Forms authentication, if it is we attempt to authenticate using Windows authentication.

Example:

```
    if (HttpContext.Current != null)
    {
        var formsAuthUser = FormsAuthenticationUser.CreateFormToken(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
        if (formsAuthUser != null)
        {
          //Authenticate using Forms authentication
        }
    }

    //Authenticate using Windows authentication
```

My problem is occurring when an NT Service that uses this code attempts to authenticate a user. Upon starting the service an exception is raised from the line `var formsAuthUser = FormsAuthenticationUser.CreateFormToken(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);`

This exception is raised because `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` is null.

My question is why would I have a non-null `HttpContext.Current` when I am accessing the context from an NT service and not one request has made to IIS?

Any input would be much appreciated; please let me know if I can provide any more information.

Comment: Trying to detect your execution environment is fraught with issues like this. Can you not turn things around so that the *consumer* of this shared class tells it explicitly what type of authentication it should be using?

Comment: This does generally seem like a bad practice, can you maybe post the whole class so we can advise you on how this can be fixed in a better way?

Comment: I agree that it isn't a reliable way of determining the authentication scheme for the current user. Unfortunately, this is impacting a live customer and it would be preferable if we could have a short-term fix while I work on designing a better approach.

Comment: Well, the short term fix is probably to check the thing you don't want to be `null` for whether it's `null`.

Comment: That makes sense to me, and that is what my colleague is working on now. I am just trying to understand why the current HttpContext is not null when there are not any requests. Thank you!